# How do I get a list of colliders within and beyond the radius?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

To optimize my game, I need to get two lists: with colliders in the radius and with colliders outside the radius.

How can this be implemented?

Comment: Since you haven't implemented anything yet, I'm not sure people will be able to answer you very precisely. Here's one approach: Locate all your GameObjects in your scene, then call GetComponentsInChildren() on them to collect their colliders. Then, either have a spherical trigger collider or use Physics.OverlapSphere() to detect colliders within your radius. If you subtract the colliders inside the radius from your master list, those are the colliders outside the radius. Try writing some code with that as a starting point, and if you run into problems you can create a new question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give more information to help people to help But I think you have an object and you want to get a list of all colliders near it with in radius **r**
you can use

```
Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(center, radius);
```

and you can convert them to list by

```
List<Collider> colliders = hitColliders.ToList();
```

and you can use the same trick with a larger raius to get all objects in the scene